# iad interstitial ad is taking too much time to load a new ad in spritkit game

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit, iad

I am using iad interstitial ads in my spritekit game. 1st of all I am not sure whether the way I am implementing it is right or not. 
I have comviewcontroller.h, comviewcontroller.m, myscene.h, myscene.m

I imported the iad framework in comviewcontroller.h like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

then i added code to open interstitial ad in my myscene class like this

```
-(void)showInterstitial{
    [self.view.window.rootViewController requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
}
```

Now I am calling this showInterstitial method after the end of the game but the issue is it is sometime working and sometime not. Whis is mostly due to not able to load a new ad after canceling the previous one. If I am using the wrong way please tell me the right way to do it.